# How to redirect url using javascript query

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

How do I redirect conditionally with query /xxx?xxx in the url link?

For example, anyone who come to my site with the below two link should be redirected to different pages.

mysite.com/contest?a => mysite.com/contest-a 
mysite.com/contest?b => mysite.com/contest-b

Can this be done using both js and meta refresh?

How do I do this using .htaccess?

Comment: Sounds like something you should be doing on the serverside, and not with javascript.

Comment: Sounds like a job for window.location = "http://www.google.com/"

Answer (score 1):

If there is a querystring, replace the first instance of `?` with `-`

```
if (window.location.search.length)
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('?','-');
```

Comment: this would cause an unnecessary page refresh. If you want to send your user to contest-a, why are you sending him to contest?a in the first place?

Comment: @PabloMescher -  And that's why I added the first comment in the question, noting that a serverside solution would be the better option, for all I know the OP could be using node.js, where this would be totally valid, not everyone uses Apache ?

Comment: Yes you are right, I used mod_rewrite because I guessed my odds were better that the OP was using PHP. It was just easier to explain through a concrete example, but the general principle applies that if you don't want the user to hit a certain url, you shouldn't wait until js is up and loaded to start a redirect. It's just too late IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
location.href
```

to detect url, where you are now. And

```
window.location.replace('mysite.com/contest-a ');
```

to do redirect.
But probably it is better to do it on server side, since it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below script to do the re-direction.

```
window.onload = function()
{
   var location = window.location;
   if(location.indexOf("contest?a") > -1)
   {
         window.location.href = "mysite.com/contest-a";
   }
   else
   {
         window.location.href = "mysite.com/contest-b";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the url without refreshing the page (except for hashes), and thus you would be better off not using that url in the first place to avoid unnecessary requests and hassle for the user. You could take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) which does that (transform a "nice url" from the user into an "ugly url" that your server actually understands)

In your example, a possible rule might be

```
RewriteRule  ^mysite.com/contest-{.+}  /mysite.com/contest?$1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok doing this kind of operation on the client side, you could embed the following snippet on your landing page (the page where the arriving user will be redirected), just after the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mapReferrer = function() {
    var gotoURL;

    switch(document.referrer) {
      case "https://www.google.com":      gotoURL = "http://<yoursite>/arrivedFromSearchEngine"; break;
      case "https://www.facebook.es":     gotoURL = "https://<yoursite>/engageFBusers"; break;
      case "http://<yoursite>/contest?b": gotoURL = "http://<yoursite>/contest-b"; break;
    };

    if (gotoURL) window.location = gotoURL;
  };

  window.onload = mapReferrer;
</script>
```